# Find if column contains specific text. If it does, get the value to the right of the cells that contains the text

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

My apologies for the title but I am not entirely sure how to word this question as it's confused me quite a bit!

[image]
Ok, essentially in F1 I am trying to get the value 02/06/2019 (from D3), and therefore G1 would show 10 (from B3 since D3 is the max timestamp for nameA). 
Using this method, F2 would be 05/06/2019 (from D5), and so G2 would be 8 (from B5).

My problem is that I am lost as to what formula to use in order to automate F:F and G:G, so that each time I make a new entry in the A, B, and D cells it will update the F and G cells. 
(say for example I make a new entry of: A6 = nameA, B6=11 and D6 = 12/06/2019, you would expect F1 and G1 to update to 12/06/2019 and 11 respectively.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't share the spreadsheet that this problem is related to since the data is of a sensitive nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E1:E, SORT(A1:C, 1, 1, 3, 0), {3, 2}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! You have saved me a very big headache :)